# JQuery event to detect after page update

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, microstrategy

I am working on JQuery where I got a page which is already developed by other team.
My task is to change headers(titles) of the tables to some specific values. So I did this easily with simple JQuery code in document.ready() event. But as I said page is already developed by some other team, If data on page is updated automatically code does'nt run and table titles are reset again. Is there any event in JQuery to detect runtime changes on web page so that I can execute my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, there isn't. (Not cross-browser atleast)

Comment: you may want to review this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3219767/1807551

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MicroStrategy doesn't provide any SDK documentation for Javascript customizations.

I had a similar problem with a customer and we had to look into the JS code and try to figure out a solution. I had the support of a very strong web developer, but anyway the solution was dirty, even if the cleanest possible.

In my case using MicroStrategy Express, I had to patch the 
`mstrmojo.all[#K_ID_OF_YOUR_GRID#].postRenderPage` function, running the original code (that I copied in a new function) plus my function that was modifying the grid.

I can't go in more details without knowing what you are trying to do, but feel free to contact me if you need additional help.

Hope this helps,
Mucio